# html formular apple autofill doesn't work

Tags: html, safari

I have a simple html formula with many input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname" placeholder="Vorname" autocomplete="given-name" required>
<input type="text" id="nachname" name="nachname" placeholder="Nachname" autocomplete="family-name" required>
<input type="text" id="firma" name="firma" placeholder="Firma" autocomplete="organization">
<input type="text" id="strasse" name="strasse" placeholder="Straße" autocomplete="address-level2" required>
<input type="text" id="plz" name="plz" placeholder="PLZ" maxlength="5" pattern="[0-9]+" autocomplete="postal-code" required>
<input type="text" id="ort" name="ort" placeholder="Ort" autocomplete="street-address" required>
<input ype="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" autocomplete="email" required>
<input type="tel" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Telefon" pattern="[0-9]+" autocomplete="tel" required>
```

If I call the website with my iPhone and I click on the first input "vorname" I get the option "Fill contact automatically".

All values will be filled automatically except "nachname","firma","Straße","PLZ"

On Safari (macOS) I get no option to filled any fields.
Where is my mistake?